# simpleCart - Modal window form and sending the shopping cart in a multidimensional array to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using the js cart simpleCart but am having a simple issue..

I have a modal pop up when the customer presses "checkout" and they have to fill in their contact details and what I have working is that the modal form on submit emails me with the filled information using the code (at the link below), however I can't figure out how to include in the same data array the shopping cart information (which I can expand on via PHP and make it look nice in their the email I receive).

Any ideas, I'm trying to get this dang thing finished asap? All and any help is appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/uDS7A/

Cart I'm using is https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js or simplecartjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an easy option, serialize `simpleCart.items` as JSON and submit that to the server. If you want to be cross-browser friendly, include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library in your page to support `JSON.stringify()` in older browsers. The implementation might look like this:

```
// redefine the emailCheckout method
simpleCart.emailCheckout = function() {
    $.post(
        // url
        "core/orderSubmission.php",
        // data, serialized as JSON
        { items: JSON.stringify(simpleCart.items) },
        // success function
        function(msg) {
            // do some stuff on success
        }
    )
};
```

(Note that we're declaring the method on the `simpleCart` instance, so you can keep this code out of the simplecart.js library. Don't ever edit library code if you can help it - it makes it super-difficult to manage library updates.)

Then in PHP you can use something like

```
$items = json_decode($_POST['items']);
```

to decode the data into an array you can format.

This all assumes that `simpleCart` is correctly bound to your form and will be automatically updated as the user selects items for the cart - I think that's the way it's supposed to work.